# Identify which plugin uses UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview, deprecated, inappbrowser

I have updated codorva-ios to ^5.1.1 and add following lines in config.xml, but still getting UIWebView warning;
`<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" /> <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine"> <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" /> </feature> <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />`

My plugins are

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/crop": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^4.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/photo-viewer": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^4.12.2",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite-porter": "^4.12.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/unique-device-id": "^4.12.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.13",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.11",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": "^1.2.5",
    "cordova-android": "^6.3.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-crop": "^0.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio": "^2.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-touch-id": "^3.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid": "^1.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.6.8",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.6.0",
    "cordova-windows": "4.4.2",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "firebase": "^5.4.1",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionic2-calendar": "^0.4.4",
    "ionic2-rating": "^1.2.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.17",
    "ng2-appinsights": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ngx-webstorage": "^2.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "uk.co.workingedge.cordova.plugin.sqliteporter": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.0"
  },
```

I have updated InAppBrowser plugin. Can anybody tell me which plugin/version using UIWebView and how I resolve it?
Please specify the plugin name which is creating problem and from which version I can replace to fix this problem.

Comment: Did you find out what plugin was using the deprecated UIWebView ?